# Map integers to specific strings in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

A data frame in pandas with two columns "**text**", "**Condition**". In "Condition" column it contains numerical values for each row of "text". Values are 1,-1,0. I would like to convert these integer values to text labels, for instance, **1 for positive, -1 for negative and 0 for neutral**. How can I achieve that?

[image: Dataframe looks like:]

Comment: Do you want to convert 1 to 'positive' and similarly to others?

Comment: yes @Mohit, that is my target for now. I have tried several ways to map but all in vain

Comment: Can you add your dataframe as text instead of an image. It's easier for others to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood you question correctly here are the following ways you can change your values.

Using [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['condition'] = df['condition'].map({1:'positive', -1:'negative', 0:'neutral'})
```

Using [Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['condition'] = df['condition'].replace({1:'positive', -1:'negative', 0:'neutral'}}
```

Comment: yep..! map should be faster too. :)